# Can't watch protected flash videos (nbcsports.com) on chrome in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, video, flash, drm

My question is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114210/how-do-i-watch-protected-flash-videos-such-as-on-nbcolympics-com-using-linux).

**My Specs:** I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and trying to stream nbcsports live extra on Chrome (or Chromium). I can't use Firefox since the stream requires flash player 19.0.0 or higher, and Firefox for Linux is limited to version 11.2.

**What's Happening:**
I try to watch a protected flash player on NBCSports.com and it just shows this spinning wheel forever. Before, it wouldn't let me get passed the login page. I would login, then it would require me to login again ad nauseam. I followed [this guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/09/how-to-watch-hulu-on-ubuntu-1404-up) to install the old HAL libraries and that seemed to fix that issue, but now I'm still having the first issue of the endless spinning wheel.
I can watch basically any other flash video: Youtube, unprotected videos on NBCSports, etc.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

I've been at this for hours and haven't been able to find a solution, any help?

Comment: The link for the spinning loading wheel is broken.

Comment: I removed it, I guess I don't have enough reputation to post pictures yet.

Comment: Put the link in a comment, and I will edit it into your post for you :)

Comment: It's almost 2020 and I'm having the exact same problem on NBC.com. It's mind-blowing that the developers behind this even get paid.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites are poorly written security wise and the browser which is trying to protect you blocks the page.  Open up your browser console to check for errors which appear in red ... for example :

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.nbcolympics.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)
```

I see above error when using [this nbcolympics.com](http://stream.nbcolympics.com/tennis-mens-singles-semifinal-2) URL ... its a badly written web page when using a modern secure browser ... site is using advertisement feeds incorrectly in a fashion too similar to techniques used by malware sites such that the browser correctly throws up its hands and shuts off that content

Alternatively, often videos get blocked when you have installed ad blocker extensions ... on Chrome you can open a new window in `incognito` mode by hitting  ctrl-shift-N  which for the lifetime of that window all extensions are disabled and so previously blocked web content ( videos ) now appear as intended

Comment: Hmm, incognito mode (with adblock extension disabled) produced the same result. It doesn't make sense why this would happen if it were the browser blocking potentially malicious content, as this works for me with google chrome in Windows, and it works presumably for the thousands of other people using chrome. Here's a screenshot of the console open when I try to load it: [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcegk.jpg)